# access remote emacs server via ssh crashed

Tags: ssh, server

I run an emacs server on a remote server.

```
emacs --daemon
```

and I access this server with

```
ssh user@server -Y 'emacsclient -c &'
```

everything works fine until I close the client.

SSH session doesn't end,once I kill the SSH session,emacs server process die...

Is there anyway to make emacs server process immortal?

The server is  Raspbian on raspberrypi.
Emacs:

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.2
```

with configure option `--with-x-toolkit=lucid`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you didn't mention the OS of the server, look into launchd-type facility that keeps a process running between resets and crashes.

Comment: converted above comment to answer below

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.Thanks [Emacs User](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/7045/emacs-user)'s help.

I used to manage emacs-server process with [byobu](http://byobu.co/).Then the process die...

Now:

```
start-stop-daemon -c $USER -d /$USERHOME --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $EMACS -- "--daemon"
```

see [EmacsAsDaemon](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon).

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention the OS of the server, look into launchd-type facility that keeps a process running between resets and crashes.